# FlowDocumentReader scroll bar visibility in Scroll viewing mode

Tags: wpf, scroll, flowdocument

I need to show FlowDocument with font size slider and search button. FlowDocumentReader in Scroll viewing mode does exactly what I want, except that it always shows vertical scroll bar, whereas I need to show it only when it will be enabled (internally ReaderScrollViewer's VerticalScrollBarVisibility is Visible, but I need Auto). How can I achieve such view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using the FlowDocumentReader in Scroll viewing mode, you can use the [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx).  The FlowDocumentScrollViewer has a [VerticalScrollBarVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) property.